# React Scroll Spy Library (organism-react-scroll-nav) not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-navigation

I am a new bee in React.js and trying to design a navigation with this package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/organism-react-scroll-nav). For my project, I need to customize a function (MenuItem). Which I have done like this

```
const Styles = {
  active: {
    height: '50px',
    width: '20px',
    color: 'blue',
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    hover: {
      border: '1px solid red',
    },
  },
}

class MenuItem extends Component {
  render() {
    const { targetInfo, style, ...reset } = this.props
    let activeStyle = null
    if (targetInfo.active) {
      activeStyle = Styles.active
    }
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          ...activeStyle,
        }}
        {...reset}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Can anyone please help?
Thank you in advance :D Happy Coding :D

Comment: I think my "ScrollSpy, ScrollReceiver," is not working and I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: I make it work. Kudos :D